# Using ctypes function in firefox ChromeWorker

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jsctypes

I am trying to use a ChromeWorker to launch a background process, like so:

```
var worker = new ChromeWorker(data.url("stun-manager.js"));
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}, false);

worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'start', 'msg': 'Hi'});
```

But where exactly do I declare all my ctypes and such? Interestingly, in stun-manager.js, if I have the following:

```
dump ("Message 1");
var {Cu} = require("chrome");
dump ("Message 2");

/*import js-ctypes */
var {ctypes} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm")
var stun_driver = ctypes.open("C:\\Users\\derek_000\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\stunnel507\\stunnel507\\bin\\win32\\stun_driver.dll");

const launch_stun = stun_driver.declare("launch_stun", ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.int32_t,  ctypes.int32_t, ctypes.char.ptr.ptr);

let argv_t = ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.char.ptr);
let argc = 2;
let argv = new argv_t(argc);
var conf_path = "C:\\Users\\derek_000\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\stunnel507\\stunnel507\\stunnel.conf";
argv[0] = ctypes.char.array()(conf_path);
argv[1] = ctypes.char.array()(conf_path);

self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    var data = e.data;
    switch (data.cmd) {
        case 'start':
            self.postMessage("Value of launch_stun " + self.launch_stun);
            self.postMessage('WORKER STARTED: ' + data.msg);
            self.postMessage("debug" + self.argv_t);
            self.postMessage("test: " + self.argv_t);
            self.postMessage(self.argv[0].readString());
            launch_stun(argc, argv );
            break;
        case 'stop':
            self.postMessage('WORKER STOPPED: ' + data.msg +
                             '. (buttons will no longer work)');
            self.close(); // Terminates the worker.
            break;
        default:
            self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
    };
}, false);
```

"Message 2" is never printed to the screen, and "Message 1" is. It's almost like I am getting a silent fail from one of those other lines, but this is the exact code I have used to launch this from main.js, before I tried to use ChromeWorker.

Any ideas? I guess it seems like stun-manager.js is failing silently, and on a related note, I can't even find it in the Browser Toolbox to debug, but I do see my main.js file there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple examples of using ChromeWorker (and also an advancement of ChromeWorker, PromiseWorker, which rocks by the way):

- [GitHub :: Noitidart / ChromeWorker](https://github.com/Noitidart/ChromeWorker)
- [GitHub :: Noitidart / PromiseWorker](https://github.com/Noitidart/PromiseWorker)

You can't do `var {ctypes} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm")` in the worker (your worker is `stun-manager.js`). That's causing an error, remove that. You can just use `ctypes` without importing anything, ChromeWorker's autoamtically have it. That should fix it.

I'll look more over your code, but definitely check out the ChromeWorker repo it will help a lot, its a very basic messaging thing between worker and main.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I will check out your github and report back if I can get something working!

Comment: follow up question: So I got this workign, and I am indeed able to finally get my ctypes library to launch from the ChromeWorker thanks to your suggestion (By passing a message to it with "start", etc). However, my library call to launch_stun() is long running. If I put a postMessage() after it, I never see it back in my main.js this is problematic for infinite-running commands, because how can I post a message to the ChromeWorker to unload the library and stop the function call? Can I load/unload the ctypes library globally somehow from main.cs?

Comment: Doing `worker.terminate()` is an interesting thought to cancel whatever the worker is doing, I'm not sure if that is how it works, we should post another question about that, maybe over at http://ask.mozilla.org they know a lot over there.

Comment: You aren't getting a postMessage after launch_stun completes? By long running do you mean it never completes until it is terminated?

Comment: Correct - what I am actually launching is a socket listener. So it will keep listening forever until something tells it to stop. Do I actually need to declare my ctypes function globally, so that the worker doesn't re-load the DLL every time it is re-entered?

Comment: Oh cool i see. I'm not sure what you mean man by loading globally to keep it from reloading dll, can u plz clarify

Comment: What I mean is, the DLL is loaded in the ChromeWorker. The function call is made, and it runs infinitely. This means that the ChromeWorker itself is "Frozen" and can not receive any more postMessage() or do anything else. When I click on a "stop" button, I need a way to tell the ChromeWorker to terminate, regardless of the return of the C function. If I had the DLL loaded from the main thread, I could force it to quit by unloading the DLL I think

Comment: Oh I see! I think you'll have to worker.terminate and reload dll when you restart chromeworker :(  Other way is to maybe make your dll poll something.

Comment: Hey @Derek I heard someone else thought of bringing async to dll like this: `using pthreads when the SPF_ASYNC flag is specified`. I'm not a C guy but do you think this would help you?

Comment: I will look into it. What I actually ended up doing is using named pipes to communicate with the DLL. It polls a named pipe server, asking for status, and then can shut itself down if it gets a shutdown message. The firefox add-on can either access the named pipe directly (i think), or use a separate C process to access the named pipe to send a stop message or whatever (what I did)